Hibernate entity: map PostgreSQL enum type to Kotlin enum type
I am using Kotlin with Hibenate and Spring Boot.
I have a PostgreSQL enum type and table as follows:
CREATE TYPE calculation_method AS ENUM ('FIXED', 'TIERED');

CREATE TABLE component_type (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    default_calculation_method calculation_method,
);

and I have the following Kotlin enum:
enum class CalculationMethod {
    FIXED, TIERED
}

and I have the following entity:
Entity
@Table(name = "component_type")
class ComponentTypeEntity (
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var defaultCalculationMethod: CalculationMethod?,

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int? = null
)

When I try to persist an entity into the database using Hibernate I get the following error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "default_calculation_method" is of type calculation_method but expression is of type character varying

How can I map my Kotlin enum type to PostgreSQL enum type using Hibenate entity?

You can tell PostgreSQL to map the varchar to the default_calculation_method PostgreSQL enumeration. Run the following on your database: CREATE CAST (varchar AS default_calculation_method) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;

There is no way to do it with Hibernate annotation. In java, you can do: @JdbcType(PostgreSQLEnumJdbcType.class)
